# Hichcharts CSV Import - Series Name

Tags: javascript, csv, highcharts

We import a CSV File into Highcharts. The first Row holds the names of the series.
Now we need to display our charts also for another language. 
How can we get the serie names and translate them? Or is there another way naming the series when importing from CSV?

We import the csv like following code:

```
 $.get('data.csv', function(csv) {
 Highcharts.setOptions({
 colors: ['#ffd800']
});
  $('.loadDiv1').hide();
  $('#chart_1').highcharts({
      chart: {
          type: 'area'
      },
      data: {
          csv: csv,
          itemDelimiter: ';',
          lineDelimiter: '\n',
          decimalPoint: ','
      },
      title: {
          text: '<?php echo $lang['79']; ?>',
          style: {
              color: '#68666b',
              fontWeight: 'bold',
              fontSize: '14px'
          }
      },
      yAxis: {
        min: 1,
        max: 10,

        tickInterval: 1,
          title: {
              text: ''
          },
          labels: {
              format: '{value} kW'
          }

      },
      legend:{
           enabled: false       
      },
      plotOptions: {
        series: {
            marker: {
                enabled: false
            }
        }
    },
      credits: {
          enabled: false
      }
  });
});
```

The CSV FIle looks like this:

```
row;Serienname 1;Serienname 2;Serienname 3;Serienname 4;Serienname 5
00:00;0,00;0,00;0,00;0,00;0,00
00:02;0,00;0,00;0,00;0,00;0,00
```

We need the "Serienname 1 -5" (the names are only examples, we use other german words)  translated in different languages.

Thank you for help
Neil

Comment: You should translate your source CSV.

Comment: Do you have a function that translates using a dictionary (or similar) or how are you going tou translate each word?

Comment: So for each language a seperate CSV? No other possibility to control/grab the names and work with them?

Comment: @ Victor   We check in PHP wich language Session is set and translate the words in seperate lang.php files loaded according to the session.

Comment: Highcharts support multiple languages but only for their default values. Check out this one "http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/lang". The CSV you are importing does not fall under the Highcarts Default Names category so you will have to either have a CSV already translated or parse the CSV with your custom function and translate it during the parsing. I personally made my own parser and i am translating it during the parsing. I am not aware of another way to translate it.

Answer (score 0):

There is an example here you can do custom preprocessing [csv custom preprocessing](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/working-with-data/custom-preprocessing#1)

And you can probably use this jquery plugin to translate [translate.js](http://www.openxrest.com/translatejs/)

[Adding classes to series](http://jsfiddle.net/j3xvg/1/)

```
chart: {
        renderTo: 'container',
        defaultSeriesType: 'line',
        marginRight: 50,
        marginBottom: 175,
        events: {
            load: function () {
                var chart = this;
                $(chart.series).each(function (i, serie) {
                    $('<li style="color: ' + serie.color + '">' + serie.name + '</li>').click(function () {
                        serie.visible ? serie.hide() : serie.show();
                    }).appendTo('#legend');
                });
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thats looks interesting. But for that I need to add a class to the Div where the Names getting dispalyed - that leads to the question: how can I get the Divs to add a class :)

Comment: did you mean just add a class to using jQuery like following?

$('#chart_1').addClass('some_class');

Comment: No, I meant to add a class to the divs where the series names get displayed.